# Обособляется ли предложение в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация

Советую покинуть данную территорию, **в целях вашей же безопасности**. Почему здесь ставится запятая перед В? Ну или почему не ставится?

Answer (score 1):

Советую покинуть данную территорию ***в целях вашей же безопасности.***

1) Обстоятельственные обороты с **производными предлогами** обособляются факультативно

2) Оборот **в начале или в конце предложения** обычно не обособляется, особенно  это касается официально-делового стиля.

3) Если нужно **выделить** оборот, то обособить его удобно  **в середине предложения:**

Советую, ***в целях вашей же безопасности***, покинуть данную территорию.

4) **В целях чего, каких. в зн. предлога.** Для чего-л.; с какой-л. целью. Усилить контроль на дорогах **в целях обеспечения безопасности движения. В целях развития региона** решено привлечь инвесторов.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор между обособлением и необособлением обстоятельства остаётся за автором высказывания.

В данном предложении запятую можно поставить, так как распространённое обстоятельство употреблено с оттенком присоединения:

***Советую покинуть данную территорию, в целях вашей же безопасности.***

Пример [обстоятельства, выраженного существительным](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114) с предлогом *в зависимости от*:

*Время обеденного перерыва устанавливается или от часа до двух, или от двух до трёх, в зависимости от характера работы предприятия* — с оттенком присоединения.